# I2C Writing protocol: how to write in a register?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c

I am programming the MAX77651 in I2c using the FT4222 device. I want to be able to write in a register.

I am able to read registers so i know i dont have any hardware problems. To read in a register i proceed like this: i first send the register i want to read then i just read what is inside.

To write i am trying to send the register where i want to write then i send the data i want to put in the register. But when i check by reading after this i dont get the expected result.

Here is the part of the programm where i try to write and read:

```
uint8 resultat=0x11;
uint8 *p_resultat=&resultat;
int chiffre = 8;
uint16 bytesToWrite2 = 1;
uint16 bytesWritten2=1;
uint8 valeur= 0x06;     // Adress of register
uint8 *p_valeur=&valeur;    
uint16         slaveAddr = 0x48;

// ***** reading test of 0x06 : expected value : 0xFF
FT4222_I2CMaster_Write(ftHandle,slaveAddr,p_valeur,
bytesToWrite2,&bytesWritten); 

chiffre = FT4222_I2CMaster_Read(ftHandle,slaveAddr,p_resultat,1, &bytesRead);
printf("The content of the register %02X is : %02X \n " , valeur , resultat);
printf("reading success if : %d = 0 \n " , chiffre);

//********** Writting test to the register 0x40 
***********************************************//

valeur = 0x40;

FT4222_I2CMaster_Write(ftHandle,slaveAddr,p_valeur,
bytesToWrite2,&bytesWritten);

valeur = 0x1F;

FT4222_I2CMaster_Write(ftHandle,slaveAddr,p_valeur,
bytesToWrite2,&bytesWritten);

//*************** Reading of the register 0x40 
*******************************************//

valeur= 0x40;           

FT4222_I2CMaster_Write(ftHandle,slaveAddr,p_valeur,
bytesToWrite2,&bytesWritten); 

chiffre = FT4222_I2CMaster_Read(ftHandle,
slaveAddr,p_resultat,1, &bytesRead);

printf("The content of the register %02X 
is : %02X \n " , valeur , resultat);

printf("reading success if : %d = 0 \n " , chiffre);
```

That code should show me 1F in the register 0x40 but it's not the case, here is what i get:

```
The content of the register 06 is : FF 
reading success if : 0 = 0 
The content of the register 40 is : 00 
reading success if : 0 = 0
```

My Question is simple, what should i do and in which order, to write properly in a register ?

Ps: I did'nt put my whole code because it is mainly configuration about FT4222 and includes, nothing relevant to solve my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the "Writing to a Single Register" section on page 76 of the [MAX77651 datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX77650-MAX77651.pdf).

> The write byte protocol is as follows:
>
> - The master sends a start command (S).
> - The master sends the 7-bit slave address followed by a write bit (R/W = 0).
> - The addressed slave asserts an acknowledge (A) by pulling SDA low.
> - The master sends an 8-bit register pointer.
> - The slave acknowledges the register pointer.
> - The master sends a data byte.
> - The slave updates with the new data
> - The slave acknowledges or not acknowledges the data byte. The next rising edge on SDA loads the data byte into its target register and
>     the data becomes active.
> - The master sends a stop condition (P) or a repeated start condition (Sr). Issuing a P ensures that the bus input filters are set for 1MHz
>     or slower operation. Issuing an Sr leaves the bus input filters in
>     their current state.

You are attempting to write to an internal register with two consecutive calls to `FT4222_I2CMaster_Write()`.  You are expecting that the first write selects the register address and the second write loads the data.  But that's not how it works.  Each call to `FT4222_I2CMaster_Write()` sends a START and STOP so your consecutive calls will result in a STOP/START between the register address and the data.   Instead you should make one call to `FT4222_I2CMaster_Write()` and provide both the register address and the data.  Maybe something like this.

```
uint8_t buf[2];
buf[0] = register_addr;
buf[1] = data;
FT4222_I2CMaster_Write(ftHandle, slaveAddr, buf, 2, &bytesWritten);
```

By the way, your reads may not be correct either.  See the "Reading from a Single Register" section of the MAX77651 datasheet.  You may need to implement a register read with calls to `FT4222_I2CMaster_WriteEx()` followed by `FT4222_I2CMaster_ReadEx()` as shown in the "I²C combined message support" example on page 32 of the [User Guide For LibFT4222](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_329_User_Guide_for_LibFT4222.pdf).

Comment: Thanks it worked sending the register address and the data in the same write instruction. It was the solution.

Comment: @kkrambo "You are expecting that the first write selects the register address and the second write loads the data. But that's not how it works." Most helpful phrase I have found after hours of searching. Thanks!